# How to import pictures to a specific slide of a Powerpoint Presentation?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I tried to use batch for the first time an I'm relatively new in the coding community.

I have tried to find a solution and I really do not care what kind of script I have to use, but I did not find a solution for my problem. This is the code that I have:

```
wscript "VBS\SC5.vbs";
timeout /T 2 /nobreak;
call screenCapture 5.png "[Tool]";

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.EXE" /N PPT_Template.potx

#Needed Import of Pictures
#(Save of the Powerpoint) Found a solution for that

timeout /T 20 /nobreak
setlocal enableextensions 
set name=%DATE:/=_%
mkdir "%name%"
move *.png %name%
move *.pptx %name%
```

The code should just import one picture at a time from folder "x" to a PowerPoint Presentation, and switch to the next slide and import the next picture. If possible it would be nice to define how large the picture should be and where I what to have it on the slide, but that is less important. I just want to continue coding and this problem got me stuck for a long time.

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with graphical user interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Com Objects in Powershell ?
It may be more convenient than using cmd.

```
$Powerpoint = New-Object -ComObject Powerpoint.Application
$yourFileName = "PPT_Template.potx" #Put here the path to your ppt file
$Presentation = $Powerpoint.Presentations.Open($YourFileName,0)
$slideNumber = 1 #The number of the slide where you want to import the picture
$Slide = $Presentation.Slides($slideNumber)
$yourImageName = "your_image.jpg" #The path to your picture
$Slide.Shapes.AddPicture($yourImageName, 0, 1, 10,10 )
$Presentation.Save()
$Powerpoint.Quit()
```

You can define the size and the position of the picture by modifying the parameters of the AddPicture method, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you really much. I will try this with PowerShell, and if I have a Problem I will inform you.